# Irish font not coming correctly in asp.net dropdown

Tags: asp.net, encoding, fonts, dropdown

In dropdownlist irish font not appearing correctly expected - Éire actual in attached image "�ire".
[image: Irish font]

Answer (score 0):

Use following setting in webconfig worked for me.(Western European encoding)

```
 <globalization culture="" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1" uiCulture="" />
```